# Twitter Sharing Not Working

Tags: twitter

I am using the standard twitter button to share links from my page.  While the button itself actually works and I am able to post through it to my twitter account, I'm having a couple of problems.

First, the count itself does not update right away. It will remain at whatever number it was before tweeting.

Second, if you click on a count that's > 0, the twitter search will not actually find the tweet.

Sample page: http://www.reviewgol.com/reviews/index

Actual Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"  
       datacount-url="http://www.reviewgol.com/reviews/view/159/J-G-Spaplus-Family-Spa-Ltd-Coquitlam-BC"  
       data-url="http://www.reviewgol.com/reviews/view/159/J-G-Spaplus-Family-Spa-Ltd-Coquitlam-BC" 
       data-text="Reviewgol: Review of J G Spaplus Family Spa Ltd, Coquitlam, BC" 
       data-count="horizontal">
    Tweet
 </a>
```

I wasn't able to find any solution to this...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Twitter does a certain amount of caching so sometimes it takes time for counts to get updated.

2) Twitter has a number of [quality filters](https://support.twitter.com/forums/10713/entries/42646) and time constraints on search results which means that not all tweets are available through search.

Comment: Thanks for your response, abraham.  So I should just move on? :)  I will accept your answer by the end of the day if nothing else comes up...

Comment: There isn't really much you can do about it so ya. I would move on to more important things. :)